# Find the domain of the function- $\mathrm{arcsin}\left(\frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7}\right)$

Tags: inequality

Could you help me find domain of the following function? 
$$\mathrm{arcsin}\left(\frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7}\right)$$

My steps-

$$-1 \leq \frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7} \leq 1 .$$

Intervals- $$(-\infty,-3/2] \text{ and } (-3/2,\infty).$$

I have a problem with solving the inequalities. Thanks for help!

Comment: The ends of the domain are where $2x+3=\pm(3x-7)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Solving $|2x+3|=3x-7$ you find the ''critical'' points :$x=10$ and $x=\frac{4}{5}$, and you can see that the given function has no real values for $\frac{4}{5}<x<10$.

---

Added.

As noted in the OP the $\arcsin$ function has real values iff its argument in between $-1$ and $1$ , i.e.:
$$-1 \leq \frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7} \leq 1 $$
these are two inequalities :
$$
-1 \leq \frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7} \qquad \land \qquad  \frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7} \leq 1 
$$ 
that we can solve in a canonical way with four systems of inequalities that  we can write as (for $3x-7 \ne 0$ ):
$$
\begin{cases}
x\ge-\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{2x+3}{3x-7}\ge-1
\end{cases}
\quad \lor \quad
\begin{cases}
x< -\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{-(2x+3)}{3x-7}\ge-1
\end{cases}
$$
for the first, **and**:
$$
\begin{cases}
x\ge-\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{2x+3}{3x-7}\le 1
\end{cases}
\quad \lor \quad
\begin{cases}
x< -\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{-(2x+3)}{3x-7}\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
for the second.

Now we can solve these systems and find the final solution (with attention to the logical connectives). All this require some algebra but it's not, in principle, difficult.

But, as in many similar cases, we can find some shortcut. In this case we note that the solution of all the systems is characterized by the solutions of the equation:

$$
|2x+3|=3x-7
$$

So we can solve this equation (that gives $x=\frac{4}{5}$ and $x=10$) and test if the argument
$$
\frac{|2x+3|}{3x-7}
$$
is $\ge -1$ and $\le 1$ in the intervals limited by the solutions:$(-\infty,\frac{4}{5}]$,$(\frac{4}{5},10)$ and $[10,-\infty)$.

Note that the value $x=\frac{7}{3}$ (where the argument dos not exists) is in $(\frac{4}{5},10)$ so the test of this interval require some attention.

Comment: Can I ask you how you get $|2x+3|=3x-7$ ? I thought that I should solve inequalities when arcsin is from interval <-1,1>.

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)